# Silverstripe Bootstrap Accordion Sidebar

Tags: loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, silverstripe

Hi Iam creating a site with silverstripe and trying to create a dynamic sidenav using bootstrap accordion, I have got it working using $Pos to create unique values for the id and data-parent attributes.

I'm running into trouble with the 3rd level items having the same ID and data-parent values as earlier items on the list as $Pos is resetting.

My code is the following:

```
<div id="extra-links-section" class="extra-nav">
<div class="list-group panel">
<% loop Menu(4) %>
    <a class="$LinkingMode list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="<% if $Children && URLSegment != 'coaches-and-managers' %>#dropdown$Pos<% else %>$Link<% end_if %>" <% if $Children && URLSegment != 'coaches-and-managers' %>data-toggle="collapse"<% end_if %> data-parent="#extra-links-section">$Title <% if $Children && URLSegment != 'coaches-and-managers' %><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i><% end_if %></a>
    <% if $Children && URLSegment != 'coaches-and-managers' %>
      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown$Pos">
        <% loop $Children %>
          <a class="$LinkingMode list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="<% if $Children %>#dropdown$Pos<% else %>$Link<% end_if %>" <% if $Children %>data-toggle="collapse"<% end_if %> data-parent="#dropdown$Pos">$Title <% if $Children %><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i><% end_if %></a>
          <% if $Children %>
            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown$Pos">
              <% loop $Children %>
                <a class="$LinkingMode list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="<% if $Children %>#dropdown$Pos<% else %>$Link<% end_if %>" <% if $Children %>data-toggle="collapse"<% end_if %> data-parent="#dropdown$Pos">$Title <% if $Children %><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i><% end_if %></a>
                <% if $Children %>
                  <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown$Pos">
                    <% loop $Children %>
                      <a class="$LinkingMode list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent="#dropdown$Pos" href="$Link">$Title</a>
                    <% end_loop %>
                  </div>
                <% end_if %>
              <% end_loop %>
            </div>
          <% end_if %>
        <% end_loop %>
      </div>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Is this functionality possible with $Pos, I can see it would work if I did not have so many children pages.. Do I need to use js to get this to work? Any help with a solution would be appreciated.

**Code output after Drawrdesign's suggestion:**
(I've removed some if the a tags because of character limit)

```
    <div class="extra-nav" id="extra-links-section">
    <div class="list-group panel">
        <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/first-xv/">First XV</a> <a class=
        "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
        "#extra-links-section" href="/sport/clubs/rugby/second-xv/">Second
        XV</a> <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/under-16/">Under 16</a> <a class=
        "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
        "#extra-links-section" href="/sport/clubs/rugby/under-15/">Under
        15</a> <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/under-14a/">Under 14A</a> <a class=
        "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
        "#extra-links-section" href="/sport/clubs/rugby/under-14b/">Under
        14B</a> <a class=
        "link list-group-item list-group-item-success collapsed"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" data-toggle="collapse" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown1-7">Draws <i class=
        "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

        <div class="list-group-submenu collapse" id="dropdown1-7" style=
        "height: 0px;">
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown7-1" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/draws/2nd-may-2015/">2nd May 2015</a>
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown7-2" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/draws/9th-may-2015/">9th May 2015</a>
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown7-3" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/draws/16th-may-2015/">16th May 2015</a>
        </div><a class=
        "link list-group-item list-group-item-success collapsed"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" data-toggle="collapse" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown1-8">Results <i class=
        "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

        <div class="list-group-submenu collapse" id="dropdown1-8" style=
        "height: 0px;">
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown8-1" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/results-2/2nd-may-2015/">2nd May 2015</a>
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown8-2" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/results-2/9th-may-2015/">9th May 2015</a>
        </div><a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/coaches-and-managers/">Coaches and Managers</a>
        <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success collapsed"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" data-toggle="collapse" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown1-10">Previous Seasons <i class=
        "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

        <div class="list-group-submenu collapse" id="dropdown1-10" style=
        "height: 0px;">
            <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown10-1" data-toggle="collapse" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown10-1">2014 <i class=
            "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

            <div class="list-group-submenu collapse in" id="dropdown10-1"
            style="height: auto;">
                <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                data-parent="#dropdown1-1" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/first-xv-2014/">First
                XV 2014</a> <a class=
                "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
                "#dropdown1-7" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown1-7">Draws <i class=
                "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

                <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown1-7">
                    <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown7-1" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/draw/5th-april-2014/">
                    5th April 2014</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown7-2" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/draw/12th-april-2014/">
                    12th April 2014</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown7-14" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/draw/9th-august-2014/">
                    9th August 2014</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown7-15" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/draw/highlanders-draw-2014/">
                    Highlanders Draw 2014</a>
                </div><a class=
                "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
                "#dropdown1-8" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown1-8">Results <i class=
                "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

                <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown1-8">
                    <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-1" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/results-2/5th-april-2014/">
                    5th April 2014</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-2" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/results-2/12th-april-2014/">
                    12th April 2014</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-13" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2014/results-2/highlanders-points-table/">
                    Highlanders Points Table</a>
                </div>
            </div><a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
            data-parent="#dropdown10-2" data-toggle="collapse" href=
            "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown10-2">2013 <i class=
            "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown10-2">
                <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                data-parent="#dropdown2-1" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/first-xv-2013/">First
                XV 2013</a> <a class=
                "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
                "#dropdown2-7" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/under-13-2013/">Under
                13 2013</a> <a class=
                "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
                "#dropdown2-8" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown2-8">Draws <i class=
                "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

                <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown2-8">
                    <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-1" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/draws/11th-15th-may-2013/">
                    11th - 15th May 2013</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-2" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/draws/18th-22nd-may-2013/">
                    18th - 22nd May 2013</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-12" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/draws/24th-30th-august-2013/">
                    24th - 30th August 2013</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown8-13" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/draws/highlanders-competition-draw/">
                    Highlanders Competition Draw</a>
                </div><a class=
                "link list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent=
                "#dropdown2-9" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                "/sport/clubs/rugby/#dropdown2-9">Results <i class=
                "fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

                <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="dropdown2-9">
                    <a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown9-1" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/results-2/11th-may-2013/">
                    11th May 2013</a>  <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown9-10" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/results-2/10th-august-2013/">
                    10th August 2013</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown9-11" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/results-2/17th-august-2013/">
                    17th August 2013</a> <a class=
                    "link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
                    data-parent="#dropdown9-12" href=
                    "/sport/clubs/rugby/previous-seasons/2013/results-2/24th-august-2013/">
                    24th August 2013</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><a class="link list-group-item list-group-item-success"
        data-parent="#extra-links-section" href=
        "/sport/clubs/rugby/contacts/">Contacts</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
{$Up.Pos}-{$Pos}
```

to get the parent's position to make the position unique.

Comment: Thanks Drawrdesign, I can see how that should work but i'm still getting a similar issue, i'll post the code that is being created so you can see the issue, my previous seasons - draws dropdown has the same values as my draws dropdown: #dropdown1-7

Comment: You could always use the URLSegment since it's unique I suppose.

e.g: href="dropdown-{$URLSegment}"

Also, you should make a recursive include to handle this, since the nested loops are generally the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I was able to get it working using dropdown-{$URLSegment}